# Multi-threading synchronization using wide scope lock with WCF callbacks

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore, wcf-callbacks

What I want to do is this--

I want to make a proxy call to a service and receive data on a separate thread through an asynchronous callback...the tricky part is that I want to make the foreground thread sleep until all of the data has been retrieved.

The reason I'm not using a synchronous method to do this, is because I'm creating an API for a WCF service that uses Paging and returns data in chunks.
I want my client to be able to use Paging, but I don't want to expose all of my Paging callbacks to my API...I want it to appear as though the API exposes a synchronous data retrieval method.

I've tried using a private static Semaphore (because it is thread agnostic,) that is accessible to the class methods and the callbacks, with a single unit capacity as a means to pause the execution.

First, I use a Semaphore.WaitOne() statement.
Then, I do a Proxy call in the foreground thread, and the service creates a thread that handles the data retrieval, and control is passed back to the client.
In the client, I immediately use a second Semaphore.WaitOne() statement.
This should pause the foreground thread execution, which it does.
Then, once the "Paging Completed" Callback is executed on a separate thread, I use Semaphore.Release()
But the foreground thread never traverses the second Semaphore statement, it stays locked and so the client freezes.

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly, or is there another locking design that would be more effective?

Comment: We'll need to see your code, multithreading is difficult stuff (more so without anything to debug).

Comment: Is it at the first time when you run the routine that the freeze occurs or is this a subsequent run? Is the first Semaphore.WaitOne call just to reduce semaphore counter to 0?

Comment: @sixlettervariables:  My code is too immense (enterprise app) to show here to get a complete picture of the WCF interplay.  I was really trying to lay out a thought experiment to see if a better object was suited for the exercise.

Comment: @user377178:  You are correct.  To reduce the counter to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to accomplish is having the foreground thread wait on data-gathering thread, you may want to consider using Tasks, which would allow you to easily accomplish what you've described here.

System.Threading.Tasks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx

Some code:

```
Task t = new Task(somethingToDo);
// Fire off the new task
t.Start();

// Wait for the task to finish...
t.Wait();

// Do something else...
```

Make sure to take a look at the details of t.Wait() in the documentation. There are some exceptions you will want to be ready for, in the event that your task fails.

Comment: Sounds good, remarkrm, I'll give it a shot.  In my research, I also found "EventWaitHandle", which looks pretty promising as well.  Thank you for your response.